# jquery writing unobtrusive javascript help

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I have the following code in jquery.

```
$(function() {
  $('.test').click(function() {
    alert('this is a test');
  });
});
```

I realize that this is unobtrusive, but I would like to try and make it even more unobtrusive by doing something like this.

```
$(function() {
  $('.test').submitAlert();

 *and place the alert message right here.
});
```

Then I would be able to call the alert message on different classes without having to retype the code. Could somebody please show how to do this to me with jquery please?

Answer (score 8):

You could wrap your code into a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.submitAlert = function(text) {
        this.bind("click", function() {
            alert(text);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$(".test").submitAlert("hello world");
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/UGsHR/1/

Comment: you made creating a plugin look easy!